# ADDED_TO_STAGE firing issues

Tags: actionscript-3, events, stage

**Resolved** - Solution with example handlers at the bottom.

Is there a way to stop the ADDED_TO_STAGE event firing multiple times.

I've noticed that by loading an external preLoader which loads my Main file, any subsequent Movieclips added to the stage or nested fire multiple times depending upon the depth.

preLoader
Main - (Add to stage) UINav
In UINav class (add any button or MovieClip)

If I test the MovieClip from the Main, 
Result Main fires once, UINav fires once, but any objects within UINav or beyond fire twice, or three times depending upon their depth.

If I test the MovieClip from the preLoader,
Result Main fires once, UINav fires once,but any objects within UINav or beyond fire three or four times depending upon their depth.

**preloader Class :**

```
package
{   

public class preLoader extends MovieClip
{

    public function preLoader()
    {
        if( stage ) added( null );
            else
            addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, added );
    }
    private function added( event:Event ):void
    {
        stage.removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, added );
        stage.removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init );
        trace( "preSite : "+ getQualifiedClassName( this ), "Initiated" );

        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.stageFocusRect = false;

        //loadStatusTxt on stage
        //preLoadText on stage

        var loader : Loader = new Loader();
        _targetLoaderInfo = loader.contentLoaderInfo;
        _targetLoaderInfo.addEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress );
        _targetLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorIOHandler);
        _targetLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE , onLoaded );

        if( Capabilities.playerType != "External" )
        {
            loader.load( new URLRequest("Main.swf?id=" + myIdentifier) );
        } else {
            loader.load( new URLRequest("Main.swf") );
        }
    }

    private function errorIOHandler( event:IOErrorEvent ):void
    {
        trace( event.text );
    }

    private function onProgress( event:ProgressEvent ):void
    {

        var loaded : uint = event.bytesLoaded;
        var total : uint = event.bytesTotal;

        var percentLoaded:Number = Math.round( (loaded/total) * 100 );

        preLoadText.text = "Loading " + percentLoaded + "%";
        addChild( preLoadText );

        pLoader.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        pLoader.y = stage.stageHeight - 50;
        addChild( pLoader );

        _loadPercent = _targetLoaderInfo.bytesLoaded / _targetLoaderInfo.bytesTotal;
        updateLoader( _targetLoaderInfo.bytesLoaded /  _targetLoaderInfo.bytesTotal );

        if ( _loadPercent >= 100 )
        {
            onLoaded( event );
        }
    }

    private function updateLoader( num:Number ) : void {
        //num is a number between 0 and 1
        pLoader.mcPreloaderBar.width = num * 476;
    }

    private function onLoaded( e:Event ):void
    {
        _targetLoaderInfo.removeEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress );
        _targetLoaderInfo.removeEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorIOHandler );
        _targetLoaderInfo.removeEventListener( Event.COMPLETE , onLoaded );

        // TODO hide loader
        removeChild( pLoader );
        while ( this.numChildren > 0 )
        {
            this.removeChildAt( 0 );
        }           
        this.addChild( DisplayObject(LoaderInfo(e.target).content) );
        trace( "Class "+ getQualifiedClassName( this ), " - COMPLETE" );
    }

}//End Class
}// End Package
```

**Main Class :**

package com.misoLepto {

```
public class Main extends MovieClip
{

    public static var test_Main : Boolean = true;// true = Live / false = TraceEvents

    public var site_Background : Site_Background = new Site_Background();
    public var site_UINav : Site_UINav = new Site_UINav();

    public function Main()
    {
        if ( stage ) init();
        else    addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init );
    }
    public function init( event : Event = null):void
    {
        if( hasEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE ))
        {
            stage.removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init );
            trace( "YES Listener Main" );
        }
        else
        {
            trace( "NO Listener Main" );
        }
        GlobalVariable.stage = stage;

        //stage.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        stage.addEventListener( Event.RESIZE, resizeMain );

        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

        setupMain();
    }
    private function toggleUINav( e:Event ):void {
        if( site_UINav.stage )
        {
            removeChild( site_UINav );
        }
        else
        {
            addChild( site_UINav );
        }
    }
    private function setupMain():void
    {
        addChild( site_UINav );
        stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, toggleUINav );
    }
    private function resizeMain( event : Event ) : void
    {
        trace("Resized Stage");
    }

}//End Class
}//End Package
```

**UINav CLass :**

```
package com.misoLepto {

public class Site_UINav extends MovieClip {

    public var site_Header : Site_Header = new Site_Header()

    public function Site_UINav()
    {
        if ( stage ) initUINav();
        else    addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initUINav, false, 0, true );
                addEventListener( Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removedUINav );
    }
    public function initUINav( event : Event = null ):void
    {

        stage.removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initUINav );
        stage.addEventListener( Event.RESIZE, resizeUINav );
        setupUINav();
    }
    private function setupUINav():void {
        trace("UINav : Initiated");
        addChild( site_Header );
    }
    private function resizeUINav( event : Event ) : void
    {
        trace("Resized Stage");
    }
    private function removedUINav ( event : Event ):void
    {           
        stage.removeEventListener( Event.RESIZE, resizeUINav );
        stage.removeEventListener( Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removedUINav );
        removeChild( site_Header );
    }

}//End Class
}//End Package
```

**Site Header Class :**

```
package com.misoLepto {


public class Site_Header extends Sprite {

    public var headPanel : Sprite = new Sprite();
    public var lineColour : uint = new uint( 0x999999 );
    public var lineWidth : Number = new Number( 1 );
    public var headerColour : uint = new uint( 0xFFFFFF );

    public function Site_Header ()
    {
        if ( stage ) initHeader();
         else
         addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initHeader, false, 0, true );
         addEventListener( Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removedHeader );
    }
    public function initHeader ( e : Event = null ):void
    {
        stage.removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initHeader );
        stage.addEventListener( Event.RESIZE, resizeHeader );

        headPanel.graphics.lineStyle( lineWidth, lineColour );
        headPanel.graphics.beginFill( headerColour, 1 );  
        headPanel.graphics.drawRoundRect( stage.stageWidth / 2, 2, stage.stageWidth / 2 - 3, 25, 10 );
        headPanel.graphics.endFill();
        trace( "HeaderPanel : Initialised" );
        addChild(headPanel);

        setupHeader();
    }
    public function resizeHeader( event : Event ) : void
    {
        if ( headPanel.stage )
        {
            headPanel.graphics.clear();
            headPanel.graphics.lineStyle( lineWidth, lineColour );
            headPanel.graphics.beginFill( headerColour, 1 );  
            headPanel.graphics.drawRoundRect( stage.stageWidth / 2, 2, stage.stageWidth / 2 - 3, 25, 10 );
            headPanel.graphics.endFill();
        }
        else
        {
            trace("headPanel not on screen");
        }
    public function removedHeader ( e : Event ):void {          
        stage.removeEventListener( Event.RESIZE, resizeHeader );
        stage.removeEventListener( Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removedHeader );
        headPanel.graphics.clear();
        removeChild( headPanel );
    }

}//End Class
}//End Package
```

**Trace results from preLoader :**

[image: preLoader Results]

**Trace results from Main :**

[image: main Results]

As you can see, the preloader fires twice for the UINav, and three times for the Header, and in the main it fires the UINav once and the header twice.

Any clues please as this is driving mental!?

I understand the essence of why this would be but if I'm adding an object within another object why does it account for if being placed on stage at each level. If I add a toggle to the highest object added, after its been removed, when it re-adds the object to the stage it only fires the once!?

Firstly, is this normal? I've seen issues raised about similar examples of ADDED_TO_STAGE firing twice and tried all but nothing makes a difference, I've cleared and removed all eventListeners after they are initialised but nothing makes a difference.

Is there a way to stop this from happenening or can someone please shed some light on the best procedure to work with nested Movieclips!? Also, if this is regular, surely this is a major drawback from using an external preloader too?

Thanks in advance.

**Resolved :** (thanks to @ices_2)

For any others suffering, here's the ammended code to use ADDED_TO_STAGE with trace handlers to see the event being added and removed.

```
public function Site_UINav()
{
        if ( this.stage ) initUINav();
        else
            this.addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initUINav );
            this.addEventListener( Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removedUINav );
    }
    public function initUINav( event : Event = null ):void
    {
        trace( "UINav listerner present (a): " + this.hasEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE ));
        if(this.hasEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE ))
        {
            //remove listener if it was added
            this.removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initUINav );
        }
        trace( "UINav listerner present (b): " + this.hasEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE ));
    }
```

**Remove the REMOVE_FROM_STAGE event :**

```
    private function removedUINav ( event : Event ):void
    {           
        stage.removeEventListener( Event.RESIZE, resizeUINav );
        trace( "UINav listerner present (c): " + this.hasEventListener( Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE ));
        if(hasEventListener( Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE ))
        {
            //remove listener if it was ever added
            this.removeEventListener( Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removedUINav );
        }
        trace( "UINav listerner present (d): " + this.hasEventListener( Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE ));
    }
```

Thanks again, so many examples online of people suffering ADDED_TO_STAGE duplicates instances and no real explanation as to how to use them correctly.

Everyday's a school day!

Comment: Please post the entire code. How do you preload `Main`? How do you display it? How do you preload `UINav`? Also, why is you code indented this way? Are you aware that the second line with `addEventListener(...)` is executed independently from the `if/else` statement and thus should be on the same indentation level like `if` and `else`? As3 ain't python!

Comment: What "external preloader" area you using? Certainly what you describe is not the way `ADDED_TO_STAGE` is supposed to work: the depth of a display object should *not* affect the number of times `ADDED_TO_STAGE` is dispatched, unless parents are removed and added multiple times.

Comment: I added the preloaderso you can see but I've tried numerous ways of adding the init starter with the recommended ADDED_TO_STAGE options many have recommended : same result.

If you load just the main, addchild (anySection ) class with ADDED_TO_STAGE for say navigation panels and buttons, then add the buttons within the ( anysection ) movieclip, they will similarly fire numerous times depending upon their nesting conditions.

I wanted Main site, load background clip, have a UINav movieclip which sits above it, within this loads all the buttons and extra features etc, above that section holder.

Comment: A simple test doesn't reproduce the issue on my end. Multiple nested children in the loaded SWF only receive the `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event once when the loader content is added. Can you simplify your example into a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Aaron : See amended code, I've added all the code for the full example, and screen grabs of the trace results for the Preloader and Main.

It clearly recognises each layer of stage for some reason and adds the same respective numbers to the stage there after!

Surely this is wrong in flash and not the code!?

Comment: @null : The code was just quickly copied for a notepad file and scuppered all indentation, I've ammended it. The if/else statements are generic ones I used as well as many other versions, this  seems to be the most common way of writing them I found when testing all options, however I have tried all versions I could find but the results were the same regardless, so I don't think that's the issue but if it is wrong or bad practice then it's good to know as I hadn't seen mention of that before.

Still clutching at straws as it's still adding too many copies each time so any clues would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not clearing event listeners because they bind to this, and not the stage.
You shold remove event listener from class like this:

```
public class Preloader extends MovieClip
{
    public function Preloader()
    {
        if (stage)
            this.init();
        else
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function added(event:Event):void
    {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        trace("added");
    }
}
```

This code will trace "added" in console only one time.

Comment: ICES_2 @ices_2 : I want to have your children. . .

This damn thing has crippled me for days now. The example I was using was taken from a tutorial I found on using the ADDED_TO_STAGE class and subsequent ones never mentioned (this) as a way of removing them.

I'd tried with the (hasEventListener) to make sure they were being removed but not been able to get the trace to detect and couldn't work out why. . . Now I know. Thanks so much, and for the others who took the time to respond. Much obliged.

Comment: I take it that this applies to the (Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE) listeners too?

And generically all classes imported should be referred to with their objects/movieClips as (this) as well! or is that redundant?

I see some cases online where people refer to the objects inherent to the class as this.mc_object etc, etc but haven't seen any clear documentation to why if so!?

Comment: yes it applies to any listener what you add, you should removing it from that you added, "this" is reference to current class(object) and can be deleted